# How to load and use classes from third-party library dll at runtime

Tags: c++, dll, dllimport, loadlibrary, getprocaddress

I have some dll (namely, a dll from Qt framework) and I want to load and use it at runtime. I know how to load it - with `LoadLibrary` I got a handle to this dll. But what next? Let's say, I want to use a class `QString` that is inside this library - how can I export it? Is it possible at all?

Comment: Nope, you cannot do that with `LoadLibrary`. You need to link to the Qt runtime in the standard way, with load time linking.

Comment: Thank you. And can you explain why?

Comment: LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress is for non-member functions rather than classes. Exporting classes requires support from the compiler and it's only viable with load time linking.

Comment: Although, if you don't want a load-time hard dependency, you can take a soft dependency instead by using delay-load, which is also managed by the toolchain, but allows you to recover from a missing DLL.